# How to attaching duplicates using pivot_wider in the tibble(or dataframe)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

When I have a dataset as below:

```r
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", 
"abc", "mno", "def", "def"), Types = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C"), values = c("x", "y", "x", "x", "z", "x", 
"y", "z", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I want to make the dataset as below using pivot_wide:

```r
  Sample A     B     C
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   abc   x;y     x
2   def     x         z;x
3   ghi     x
4   jkl           z
5   mno                 y
```

I tried to run the code:

```
a<- mut_simple %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Types, values_from = values)
```

But there are some warning messages about the duplicates (e.g. abc-A, def-C). 
How can I advance the pivot_wider deliminating the duplicates using ; ?

Comment: Can you please use ```dput()``` to share your data? This will make the job easier for everyone!

Comment: @Shibaprasadb Sure! I'll try to edit the question. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the function that you want to apply for the duplicates in `values_fn` -

```
df <- tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Types, values_from = values, 
                   values_fn = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ';'))

df

#  Sample A     B     C    
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 abc    x;y   x     NA   
#2 def    x     NA    z;x  
#3 ghi    x     NA    NA   
#4 jkl    NA    z     NA   
#5 mno    NA    NA    y
```

---

Similarly, in `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), Sample~Types, value.var = 'values', 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ';'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", 
"abc", "mno", "def", "def"), Types = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C"), values = c("x", "y", "x", "x", "z", "x", 
"y", "z", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I runned your code, but duplicated values were not attached with ;. I'll check my code, but can you suggest any additional solution?

Comment: I have added data below my answer for you to check. I hope you have assigned the dataframe back to `df <- tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try as you mentioned. Also, thank you for your data code. It was also helpful to my first StackOverflow practice.